# Firebase Facebook Login - Detect User login status and redirect

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm trying to create a login page for an app that uses the Facebook Login SDK. When the RootViewController loads, it should determine if the user has already logged in via Facebook and if so, direct them to the app's homepage. Otherwise, it should direct them to the login page to login if they haven't logged in via Facebook.

I have added code to the RootViewController that checks if currentUser is nil, however it seems to redirect to the homepage no matter if the user has logged in via Facebook or not.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class RootNavController: UINavigationController {

    var handler: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        handler = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            self.checkLoggedInUserStatus()
        })
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        guard let handler = handler else { return }
        Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handler)
    }

    fileprivate func checkLoggedInUserStatus() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
                let controller = WelcomeController()
                let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
                self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            } else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "UserLoggedIn", sender: nil)
                return
            }
        }

    }
```

Expected results would be to show the homepage only if the user has already logged in via Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from a quick change, your code seems fine. It should work as long as you logout the user before opening the app again. Remember that Fb login only gives you a token to authenticate in firebase. After that all the login and logout needs to be handled in Firebase. I would change your code like this. But mostly for simplicity:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        handler = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if user != nil {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "UserLoggedIn", sender: nil)
            } else {
                let controller = WelcomeController()
                let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
                self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
```

And maybe it would be better if you do all this in the AppDelegate. That way you don't have to present a NavBar without the need of it. Instead you could just present the required screen after the app launch screen.